# Filtering Multi-Selection Lists

Tags: 2010, infopath, filter

I am having trouble filtering a multi-selection list, and I think the problem is with the reference to the current item.  I need a way to reference the item that the filter is being checked against (it is a somewhat complex filter, and I need to access this information in a location that doesn't work with the '.' operator).  Does anyone know how to do this?